# Flutter - Gradle 7.2.1 Error - unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest><application>

Tags: android, flutter, build

I tried running an application in my Mac M1 in Android Studio and I get the error : `packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:89: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest><application>.`

If I use an older version for Gradle, I have this error `General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 62`

**gradle-wrapper.properties :** https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip

**build.gradle :** classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'

`flutter doctor` : everything is OK

Can you help me please ?

Comment: you should write queries code in out of application tag not inside application tag inside manifest file

Comment: Thank's for your response !